# How could someone conclude $\check{H}^i (M, \mathbb{R}) = 0$ for arbitrary $M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

sorry if this is a very stupid question and I'm missing something very trivial, though I could not solve it after thinking for a while.

In page 18-19 of http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780817649586-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-993379-p174035557, the author concludes that $\check{H}^i (M, \mathbb{R}) = 0$ for $i = 1, 2$ in order to get an isomorphism $H^1 (M, S^1) = H^2 (M, \mathbb{Z})$.

Ok, I agree with the latter one, which should be given by assigning the Euler class, however the first one ($\check{H}^i (M, \mathbb{R}) = 0$) is an absurd. It's well known that \v{C}ech cohomology with values in the constant sheaf $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to the de Rham cohomology, so clearly something is wrong.

Where's the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the link in your post meant to be chapter 2 of _Riemannian Geometry of Contact and Symplectic Manifolds_ by Blair, https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4959-3_2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of two different things when you say "the sheaf $\Bbb R$". You mean the constant sheaf, wherein $\mathcal F(U)=\Bbb R$ for any open set $U$. The author is thinking of the sheaf of sections of the trivial bundle $\Bbb R$, also known as "The sheaf of smooth functions"; so in their case $\mathcal F(U)=C^\infty(U,\Bbb R)$. This is a fine sheaf, so indeed its higher cohomology does vanish.

In your setup, the sheaf that fits in the end of $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb R \to S^1$ is actually the constant sheaf over the group $S^1$. You can of course still take its cohomology but it doesn't calculate anything interesting (like, say, complex line bundles).

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks I've got it, it's the yoneda embedding and it's the exponential sequence. Of course the cohomology is zero since the sheaf is fine and, then acyclic. Now this makes sense. But I could not understand your last statement that the $S^1$ at the end of the exact sequence is actually the constant sheaf. Isn't it $C^{\infty} (-, S^1)$?

Comment: @user40276: What I meant was that if you were using your interpretation of $\Bbb R$ (the constant sheaf), the quotient $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is the constant sheaf $S^1$, and that you get a corresponding exact sequence. With the author's interpretation you're correct that $S^1$ means the sheaf $C^\infty(-,S^1)$.